# Refresh fragment in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager that has 3 tabs. Tab(3), beside stock fragment, includes 2 more fragments (B) --> (C).

```
Tab(1)
Tab(2)
Tab(3) --> (B) --> (C)
```

By pressing a button in (C) I want to refresh/recreate Tab(2).
What's the best way to do it? Thank you.

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Context mContext;

    public ViewPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0: return new FragmentInsta();
            case 1: return new FragmentListUnlogged();
            case 2: return new FragmentHostUnlogged();
            default:
                return new FragmentListLogged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: what changes you want to do on tab (2) when you refresh it? are they visual changes or something ?

Comment: In the beginning of Tab(2) fragment I have a validation if user is logged in.
If yes, then it replaces current fragment with userIsLoggedFragment.
So I want to refresh Tab(2) to validate again.

Comment: so it replaces the whole layout in onCreateView?

Comment: Yes, I have two separate full screen layouts

Comment: As you are using `super(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);` in the Fragment you want to refresh, just put your code to refresh in the `onResume` method, so when the user view Tab(2) fragment it will be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user named "Andrew" I found the solution.
I override the onPause method in this way.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(preferenceUtils.getBoolean("isLogged")){
        FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.listUnlogged_container, new FragmentListLogged(), "ListUnlogged-ListLogged");
        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        trans.addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_TAG);
        trans.commit();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```